# What are the Instruction's required to create a SFT?

Tags: metadata

I am not sure on what are the instruction's that goes into creating a Semi Fungible Token on Solana. Will really appriciate if anyone can guide me on the right instruction's for creating one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview#semi-fungible-tokens

According to the definition by metaplex, a "sft" is essentially a token that has 0 decimals and does not have a supply cap of 1.

To create such a token, simply create a new mint with 0 decimals and a metadata account for it. This can be done through the metaplex sdk or by creating a custom program that follows the same steps.

Additionally, you can set the mint authority to a PDA of your program and create an instruction to enable token minting by your program.